# Plot data using facet-grid in seaborn

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization, facet-grid

I have this dataset   [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kWuQ.png)
And i want to plot **profit** made by different **sub_category** in different **region**.

now i am using this code to make a plot using seaborn

```
sns.barplot(data=sub_category_profit,x="sub_category",y="profit",hue="region")
```

I am getting a extreamly huge plot like this [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXIzf.png)
is there is any way i can get sub-plots of this like a facet-gird. Like subplots of different sub_category. I have used the facet grid function but it is the also not working properly.

```
g=sns.FacetGrid(data=sub_category_profit,col="sub_category")
g.map(sns.barplot(data=sub_category_profit,x="region",y="profit"))
```

I am getting the following [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXmn2.png)

As you can see in the facet grid output the plots are very small and the bar graph is just present on one grid.

Comment: As per the documentation, it is not recommended to directly use [`FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html). Instead, use [`sns.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) with `kind='bar'`. `g = sns.catplot(kind='bar', data=sub_category_profit, x="region", y="profit", col="sub_category", col_wrap=3)`

Answer (score -1):

See docs on [**`seaborn.FacetGrid`**](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html), particularly the posted example, where you should not pass the data again in the `map` call but simply the plot function and `x` and `y` variables to draw plots to corresponding facets.

Also, consider the `col_wrap` argument since you do not specify `row` to avoid the very wide plot output.

```py
g=sns.FacetGrid(data=sub_category_profit, col="sub_category", col_wrap=4)
g.map_dataframe(sns.barplot, x="region", y="profit")
```

Comment: It is not working without passing the data again in map. It says "Could not interpret input 'region' ". And when i am passing the data into it i am getting same plot on every grid.

Comment: Interesting. Try using [`map_dataframe`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.map_dataframe.html) in place of `map`. Alternatively, do not use named args `x` and `y`.

Comment: thank you so much it worked this time with map_dataframe. But i am not getting name of points on X-axis  on every gird its just on the gird of the last row. Is there is any way to solve that. And again thanks for your help.

Comment: Pass `sharex=False` and `sharey=False` in `FacetGrid`

Comment: wow thank you so much the plot looks really amazing now.